# How to create an sqlite function in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

how to create the sqlite function in objective c.
call the function for inserting the query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ListDates
(
     @StartDate    DATETIME  
    ,@EndDate      DATETIME
)
RETURNS
@DateList table
(
    Date datetime
)
AS
BEGIN

/*add some validation logic of your own to make sure that the inputs are sound.Adjust the rest as needed*/

  INSERT INTO
    @DateList
  SELECT FLD_Date FROM TableOfDates (NOLOCK) WHERE FLD_Date >= @StartDate AND FLD_Date <= @EndDate
  RETURN
END
```

Comment: SQLite doesn't do stored procedures. Is there any reason why it has to be a stored procedure, rather than just writing Objective-C code to insert these records?

Comment: Thank you Rob, i go for query.